# Creating configurable product with two set of attributes depending on each other

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-attribute

What I want to do should be possible but I can't figure out how to do it.

Let's say I'm selling shirts, I have two colours of the same shirt, let's say red and blue. now in red I only have sizes S,M,X,XL but for blue we decided to have XXL as well as the sizes available for red, how can I do this? The sizes need to change base on the colour that the customer choose, and I know I can make two different products for red and blue but I want the customer to see everything in a single page.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You make a configurable product with colour and size as configurable attributes. You then make several simple products as follows and these are associated with the configurable product:

Red S, Red M, Red L, Red XL, Blue S, Blue M, Blue L, Blue XL, Blue XXL

The customer only sees a single page (the configurable product) and will be given the choice of size/colour combinations as defined.

Comment: My problem is when I choose the colour red and blue and also the sizes S,M,XL,XXL it would automatically apply the sizes to both of colours, I want it the XXL to only be applied to one colour which I don't know how it can be done

Comment: Unless you have created a simple product with a combination of colour and size it will not display.So check if you did create a non existent simple product.

Comment: @Mr_Parham This sounds like you're creating the "Create Product Configurations" tool. You can just complete this process and then later find the Red XXL simple product and delete it.